# Парсинг table width=580 при помощи phpQuery

Tags: php, phpquery

Каким образом можно парсить подобные таблицы, которые не имеют классов? Мне нужно спарсить журналы с сайта elibrary.ru. Пример журнала https://www.elibrary.ru/title_about.asp?id=66888

Структура там довольно запутанная.

Пробовал таким вот образом получать название журнала

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
        $entry = $doc->find('table:has(td):eq(37) td:eq(2)');
        $data['name'] = pq($entry)->text();
```

У одного журнала могу получить название, а у другого уже нет. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: помнится коллега запустил парсер елайбрари без пауз и в итоге универ там забанили :D

Comment: какие именно данные надо вытащить? мб их например можно вытащить не с этой страницы а из поисковой. В целом для удобства можно убить всякие мусорные теги вида `<b>,<font>`, потом уже строить перебор `td` и искать в них значения вида "Полное наименование". если найдено, то в следующей ячейке брать само название. И можно еще ориентироваться, что после очистки b/font у интересующих тегов не будет вложенных

Comment: ну и собственно общий совет - сначала скачайте интересующие страницы, а потом уже занимайтесь разбором, чтобы не запрашивать каждый раз их с сервера

Comment: @teran, нужно парсить разные поля (название, год основания, выпусков в год, статей в выпуске, всего статей, всего выпусков и т.д.).

Пробовал парсить при помощи Datacol с подобными регулярками >Полное название</font></td>(.*?)</td> Собственно он парсит, но нужно именно на PHP, чтобы автоматически всё работало.

Можно ли на PHP как-то использовать подобные регулярки как в Datacol?

Comment: я вам вроде алгоритм описал, он чем-то не подходит, или что? Составили себе список полей `["scopus", "РИНЦ"]`, далее перебираете все `td`. Если текст в ней равен однмоу из ваших полей, то в качестве значения берете текст следующей ячейки. Тут не нужны никакие ни регулярки, ни индексы ячеек и ничего более. Вообще возможно проще будет работать с simple html dom,а не phpquery.

Comment: @teran, от мусора почистил. А дальше не совсем понял, что вы предлагаете.

Comment: предлагаю цикл в виде `foreach($html->find("td") as $td)` а внутри проверять `if ($td->text() == "scopus")` и если совпало, то `$result['scopus'] = $td->nextSibling()->text()`. Код условный, phpQuery я особо не юзал.

Comment: @teran, да, ругается на nextSibling

Comment: @teran, как-то так

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

        foreach ($doc->find("td") as $td) {
            if (pq($td)->text() == "Полное название") {
                $data['name'] = pq($td)->next()->text();
            }           
        }

Comment: @teran, осталось придумать как обойти их защиту)